# Squid configuration is not sending RESPMOD icap request, how to resolve?

Tags: proxy, squid, icap

I currently have a squid server (4.10) that I am trying to get icap working correctly on.  I have the `squid.conf` configured with both a REQMOD and RESPMOD service, however I never see squid even requesting the options for the RESPMOD endpoint.  I am attaching my config below and just wondering if there is something that I am missing that is required for squid to work.  Thanks in advance for any guidance.

```
icap_enable on
icap_service service_req reqmod_precache bypass=1 icap://icapserver:1344/req
adaptation_access service_req allow all
icap_service service_resp respmod_precache bypass=1 icap://icapserver:1344/resp
adaptation_access service_resp allow all
icap_preview_enable off
```

Comment: Which ICAP server is this?

Comment: Did you ever managed to find a solution?